# Can WebStorm resolve child attributes of the parameters to a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, webstorm

Lets say I have a function:

```
var test = function(var1, var2) 
{
    if(var1.ATTRIBUTE1)
        // do something
    else if(var2.CHILD)
        // do something
}
```

Here ATTRIBUTE1 and CHILD are usually marked as unresolved variables and a warning is raised.

Is there a way I can provide information to WebStorm about such things to eliminate the warnings?

Answer (score 1):

You can tell webstorm the shape in annotations

```
/**
 * @param var1.ATTRIBUTE1
 * @param var2.CHILD
*/
const test = (var1, var2) => {
  if (var1.ATTRIBUTE1) {
  } else if (var2.CHILD) {
  }
}
```

You can find more information under [this link](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-param.html#parameters-with-properties)

Answer (score 1):

You can use JSDoc comments for this.

#### Using [official JSDoc 3 way](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-param.html#parameters-with-properties):

```
/**
 * @param {Object} var1
 * @param {boolean} var1.ATTRIBUTE1
 * @param {Object} var2
 * @param {boolean} var2.CHILD
 */
const test = (var1, var2) => {
    if (var1.ATTRIBUTE1) {
    } else if (var2.CHILD) {
    }
}
```

#### simplified form:

```
/**
 * @param var1.ATTRIBUTE1
 * @param var2.CHILD
 */
const test = (var1, var2) => {
  if (var1.ATTRIBUTE1) {
  } else if (var2.CHILD) {
  }
}
```

#### and one more:

```
/**
 * @param {{ATTRIBUTE1:boolean}} var1
 * @param {{CHILD:boolean}} var2
 */
const test = (var1, var2) => {
    if (var1.ATTRIBUTE1) {
    } else if (var2.CHILD) {
    }
}
```